# Having a problem finding those records between yesterday and today based on a UTC column value using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Using PostgreSQL and trying to query a table that contains a UTC column.  The UTC column is a column without the timezone as I understand it from the developer.  Example in my DB for a record is (2021-08-26 13:59:26.867578).  And I have to search for records that are between yesterday's date and today's date.  When I tried the SQL statement below I get this error:

[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone - integer Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 63

Here is my SQL statement for PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT omd.*
FROM "OCRMetaDatas" omd
WHERE (omd."ScannedAt")-5 BETWEEN Now()-1 and now()
ORDER BY omd."ScannedAt" desc;
```

Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: If you are really interested in dates then `current_date - 1 and current_date`.  Also define `UTC` column and what the values are in it as update your question.

Comment: I understand from the developer that I needed to use the -5 for the column due to it being defined as a timestamp (UTC) which does not have a timezone.  I'm not sure if that makes sense .  I've not used UTC dates before.  Adrian, I updated the ticket with an example UTC date in my DB column.

Comment: this is an operator error, this is not related to UTC date, but with the operation as stated in the hint. you can't substract integer to a date (UTC or not). You must use `INTERVAL` for those kind of operations

Comment: @fpietka actually you can subtract an integer from a `date` (see my example) you just can't from a `timestamp(tz)`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver to be honest I've never even tried as it wouldn't be clear what I am substracting. Does it default to a number of days? I find `INTERVAL` more explicit imho

Comment: It is spelled out here [Date/time operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) "date - integer → date Subtract a number of days from a date date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustration of how to use `at time zone`:

```
--My TimeZone
show TimeZone;
 TimeZone  
------------
 US/Pacific

select '2021-08-26 13:59:26.867578'::timestamp;
timestamp          
----------------------------
 2021-08-26 13:59:26.867578

select '2021-08-26 13:59:26.867578'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC';
           timezone            
-------------------------------
 2021-08-26 06:59:26.867578-07

select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2021-08-26 09:23:57.818477-07
```

`at time zone` will normalize the timestamps to the same time zone.

Answer (score 2):

You can't operate integer with datetimes. Here you are trying to do that twice:

```sql
(omd."ScannedAt")-5
```

and

```sql
 Now()-1
```

You should use `INTERVAL` with datetime there, such as:

```sql
SELECT omd.*
FROM "OCRMetaDatas" omd
WHERE (omd."ScannedAt")- '5 days'::INTERVAL BETWEEN Now()- '1 day'::INTERVAL and now()
ORDER BY omd."ScannedAt" desc;
```

Comment: I tried your code but it's not returning any records though there are records between yesterday and today.

Comment: it is then related to your dataset. maybe the `BETWEEN` clause is too restrictive. your not querying data from yesterday, but data that will be `ScannedAt` in 4 days (ScannedAt date minus 5 days date must be yesterday)

Comment: replace `(omd."ScannedAt")- '5 days'::INTERVAL` with just `(omd."ScannedAt")` and you'll have those scanned yesterday

Comment: The issue I had was that the (omd."ScannedAt") -'5 hours' and NOT (omd."ScannedAt") -'5 days'.  That is why I was NOT getting any records.  Thank you for everyone's help.  Learned a lot today.

Comment: Instead of specifying `-5 hours` use `at time zone 'UTC'` this will automatically pickup the client setting for  `TimeZone` which is also used by `now()`. See my answer for illustration.